# regression result producing NA values in r

Tags: r, string

I create a variable column in excel and paste it in my data frame.  After that when I run Fama Macbeth regression including that column as an independent variable, it shows an error message like

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 133.0 Gb
```

After that, I check that column by using dput function and find numbers like string.

```
"0.035938782"
```

to destring that column I create another column by using

```
df$col2<-as.numeric(df$col1)
```

it shows a warning message  like this but create a new column

```
Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion
```

when I regress using that new column regression result produces only NA values like this

```
(Intercept) 1.9161e-05 8.0361e-04  0.0238   0.9810
max         4.8040e-02 6.2707e-02  0.7661   0.4436
col2            NA         NA      NA       NA
```

Could you please help me in this regard?

Comment: Can you tell a particular case where this happened?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your point @adjustedR2

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data and the lines of code you used for the regression.  There might be a problem with the variable class causing the error.  If there is bad data in `col1` ie a mix of number and characters, that would generate the NA and cause the regression to incorrectly calcualate.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M38vuwhvz21_iPbqkmdEgy_uOylYrH_p

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M38vuwhvz21_iPbqkmdEgy_uOylYrH_p

Comment: above two link will give you data and code. thanks @Dave2e

Comment: Both links are the same

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tN3i1bgODU39Wm2McACc8ShxmgAmvzu7

Comment: sorry this is the code link@CarlesSansFuentes

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check that the column `class()` is "character". If it is "factor", you may need to do `as.numeric(as.character(df$col1))`. I hope that solves it.

Comment: Sorry it changing class but the warning messages and NA output still exist